# How to count duplicate entries in a column

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables:

Provider:

```
 PROV_NO      P_NAME
----------  ---------- 
  P10         ANTEL
  P20         BCORP
  P30         CBIZ
```

Service:

```
S_TYPE  PROV_NO   R_PRICE
------- -------- ---------
  1      P10       160
  2      P10       180
  3      P10       110
  1      P20       190
  2      P20       180
  3      P20       150
  4      P20       240      
  5      P20       195
  1      P30       190
  2      P30       210
```

I am trying to count the number of services each provider offers and to display the counts for each next to the providers name. So I want my output to be:

```
 P_NAME     COUNT
---------  --------
 ANTEL        3
 BCORP        5
 CBIZ         2
```

My attempt:

```
select provider.p_name, count(distinct service.prov_no)
from provider,service
group by provider.p_name
```

I have tried a few ways, but I cant seem to separate the counts and make them unique for each p_name.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
select p.p_name, count(*)
from provider p
join service s on p.prov_no = s.prov_no
group by provider.p_name
```

Change `join` to `left join` if you want to include providers with no services.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the join condition and you need to drop the `distinct`:

```
select provider.p_name, count(*)
from provider,service
where provider.prov_no = service.prov_no
group by provider.p_name
```

Comment: He also needs a `count(*)`, not a `count(distinct prov_no)` - otherwise the count will always be returned as 1.

Answer (score 0):

You should have join condition in your query

```
select provider.p_name, count(distinct service.prov_no) 
from provider join service on provider.prov_no=service.prov_no
group by provider.p_name
```